# How do I import XLSX files into R Dataframe While Maintaining Carriage Returns and Line Breaks?

Tags: r, dataframe, xlsx, xls

I want to ingest all files in the working directory and scan all rows for line breaks or carriage returns. Instead of eliminating them, I'd like to divert them into a new output file for manual review. Here's what I have so far:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)


filenames <- list.files(pattern = "Sara Lee.*\\.xlsx$", ignore.case = TRUE)

read_excel_filename <- function(filename){
  ret <- read_excel(filename, col_names = TRUE, skip = 5, trim_ws = FALSE)
  ret
}

import.list <- ldply(filenames, read_excel_filename)

returnornewline <- import.list[((import.list$"CUSTOMER SEGMENT")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"SECTOR NAME")=="[\r\n]"|
                                 (import.list$"LOCATION NAME")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"LOCATION ID")=="[\r\n]"|
                                 (import.list$"ADDRESS")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"CITY")=="[\r\n]"|
                                 (import.list$"STATE")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"ZIP CODE")=="[\r\n]"|
                                 (import.list$"DISTRIBUTOR NAME")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"REDISTRIBUTOR NAME")=="[\r\n]"|
                                 (import.list$"TRANS DATE")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"DIST. INVOICE")=="[\r\n]"|
                                 (import.list$"ITEM MIN")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"ITEM LABEL")=="[\r\n]"|
                                 (import.list$"ITEM DESC")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"PACK SIZE")=="[\r\n]"|
                                 (import.list$"REBATEABLE UOM")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"QUANTITY")=="[\r\n]"|
                                 (import.list$"SALES VOLUME")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"X__1")=="[\r\n]"|
                                 (import.list$"X__2")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"X__3")=="[\r\n]"|
                                 (import.list$"VA PER")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"VA PER CODE")=="[\r\n]"|
                                 (import.list$"TOTAL REBATE")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"TOTAL ADMIN FEE")=="[\r\n]"|
                                 (import.list$"TOTAL INVOICED")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"STD VA PER")=="[\r\n]"|
                                 (import.list$"STD VA PER CODE")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"EXC TYPE CODE")=="[\r\n]"|
                                 (import.list$"EXC EXC VA PER")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"EXC VA PER CODE")=="[\r\n]"), ]


now <- Sys.time()

carriage_return_file_name <- paste(format(now,"%Y%m%d"),"ROWS with Carriage Returns or New Lines.csv",sep="_")
write.csv(returnornewline, carriage_return_file_name, row.names = FALSE)
```

Here's some sample data:

```
Customer Segment     Address
BuyFood             123 Main St.\r

BigKetchup          679 Smith Dr.\r

DownUnderMeat       410 Crocodile Way
BuyFood             123 Main St.
```

I thought the trim_ws = FALSE condition would work, but it hasn't.

Apologies for the column spam, I've yet to figure out an easier way to scan all the columns without listing them. Any help on that issue is appreciated as well.

EDIT: Added some sample data. I don't know how to show a carriage return in the address other than the regex of it. It doesn't look like that in the real sample data, that's just for our use here. Please let me know if that's not clear. The desired output would take the first 2 rows of data where there's a carriage return and output it to the csv file listed at the end of the code block.

EDIT 2: I used the code provided in the suggestion in place of the original long list of columns as follows. However, this doesn't give me a new variable that contains a dataframe of rows with new lines or carriage returns. When I look at my global environment in R Studio I see another variable under Data called "returnornewline" but it shows as a large list, unlike the import.list variable which shows a dataframe. This shouldn't be the case because I've only added a carriage return in the first row of the first spreadsheet of the data, so that list should not be so large.:

```
returnornewline <- lapply(import.list, function(x) lapply(x, function(s) grep("\r", s)))

# returnornewline <- import.list[((import.list$"CUSTOMER SEGMENT")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"SECTOR NAME")=="[\r\n]"|
#                                  (import.list$"LOCATION NAME")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"LOCATION ID")=="[\r\n]"|
#                                  (import.list$"ADDRESS")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"CITY")=="[\r\n]"|
#                                  (import.list$"STATE")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"ZIP CODE")=="[\r\n]"|
#                                  (import.list$"DISTRIBUTOR NAME")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"REDISTRIBUTOR NAME")=="[\r\n]"|
#                                  (import.list$"TRANS DATE")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"DIST. INVOICE")=="[\r\n]"|
#                                  (import.list$"ITEM MIN")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"ITEM LABEL")=="[\r\n]"|
#                                  (import.list$"ITEM DESC")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"PACK SIZE")=="[\r\n]"|
#                                  (import.list$"REBATEABLE UOM")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"QUANTITY")=="[\r\n]"|
#                                  (import.list$"SALES VOLUME")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"X__1")=="[\r\n]"|
#                                  (import.list$"X__2")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"X__3")=="[\r\n]"|
#                                  (import.list$"VA PER")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"VA PER CODE")=="[\r\n]"|
#                                  (import.list$"TOTAL REBATE")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"TOTAL ADMIN FEE")=="[\r\n]"|
#                                  (import.list$"TOTAL INVOICED")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"STD VA PER")=="[\r\n]"|
#                                  (import.list$"STD VA PER CODE")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"EXC TYPE CODE")=="[\r\n]"|
#                                  (import.list$"EXC EXC VA PER")=="[\r\n]"|(import.list$"EXC VA PER CODE")=="[\r\n]"), ]
```

EDIT 3: I need to be able to take all rows in the newly created data frame "import.list" and scan them for any instances of carriage returns or new lines within all the rows. The example above is rudimentary, but the concept stands. In the example, I'd expect for the script to read the first two rows and say "hey, these rows have carriage returns, add this to the variable assigned to this line of code and at the end of the script output this data to a csv." The remaining two rows in the sample data above have no need to be output because they have no carriage returns in their data.

Comment: To apply to all columns of all `import.list` data frames without listing, something like `lapply(import.list, function(x) lapply(x, "==", "[\r\n]"))`. But `grep` or `grepl` might do you better than `==` depending if you want to check whether a cell is `[\r\n]` or if a cell *contains* `\r\n`. A little sample input and desired output would make this a much better question.

Comment: I've added sample data. Let me know if I need to provide additional info. Also, yes, I'd like to know whether a cell is [\r\n] or contains \r\n. Good catch.

Comment: Given that sample, I think `lapply(import.list, function(x) lapply(x, function(s) grep("\r", s)))` should work. I'd like to see a sample of R output produced by `cat()` to know what's really there...

Comment: Please see my second edit. I may have applied your suggestion incorrectly, but it's not producing what I thought it would.

Comment: Sorry - I was under the impression that `import.list` was a `list` of data frames. Looks like it's a single data frame. Try `as.data.frame(lapply(import.list, function(s) grep("\r", s)))`.

Comment: I'll keep researching, but the code produces this result:

`Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1`

Comment: Ah, yes. That makes sense because different columns will have different numbers of carriage returns. What output are you hoping for? If you just want individual cells, use the code from my last comment without the `as.data.frame()`. Otherwise, edit your question to include the output you would like for your sample input.

Comment: I want to scan the entire import.list data frame and divert all rows that contain at least one carriage return or new line to a different csv that I've coded at the end of my code block. If there aren't carriage returns or new lines then that csv is empty. If there are carriage returns then I want to review them in that output csv. I want the whole row to appear in the csv, not just the offending cell.